# add space between elements in placeholder

Tags: html, css, sass

i'm trying to make an input like this where i should put the icon on the right and the text on the left :

[image]

i already try this but i think it's not a good idea:

```
 <div class="form-group">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="FirstName" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="FirstName &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &#xf2c0;">
</div>
```

any ideas ?

Comment: I removed the [tag:angular] tag as that is not related to css / styling unless you are wanting to use [tag:angular-material].

Comment: There is more than one way to do this depending on preferences including the icon library. See also: https://www.google.com/search?q=css+add+icon+to+input+placeholder+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could show the placeholder icon as a background image and then hide it using the negation of `:placeholder-shown`.

[image]

```css
[type=email] {
  background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/131/131155.svg);
  background-position: calc(100% - 8px)  center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 16px 16px;
  padding: 1em 16px 1em 1em;
  border: 1px solid;
}

[type=email]:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  background-image: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="FirstName" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="FirstName">
</div>
```

Comment: Nice answer! I'd suggest `background-position: right 8px center;`, just because I'm annoying an picky :)

Answer (score 0):

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  word-spacing: 9px !important;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  word-spacing: 9px !important;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  word-spacing: 9px !important;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  word-spacing: 9px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the input and icon into a `<div>` and remove the border from the input and add it to the `<div>`

```
<div class="" style='border:1px solid black; width: 150px'>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" style="border:0px;" />
   &#xf2c0;
</div>
```

i dont think there is any way to align the text and icon differently within the same placeholder text